# Exponential diophantine equation of the form $x^x + y^y = 2 z^z$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Suppose that $x,y,z$ are natural numbers and
$$x^x + y^y = 2 z^z$$
Prove that $x=y=z$.

Comment: Is there a reason you think we can conclude that?

Comment: If the equation held, either $x^x$ or $y^y$ (say $x^x$) should satisfy $z^z\le x^x\le 2z^z$.

Comment: @JoeyZou: A cute way! You could flesh it out to an answer.

Comment: @JoeyZou You can tell that $z$ is between $x$ and $y$, too.

Comment: The equation mod 2 reads $x^x + y^y=0$, from which it follows that $x+y=0$ modulo 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $z<y$:
$$z<y \implies z+1 \leq y $$
then
$$2z^z < z^{z+1}+(z+1)z^z\leq y^y$$
therefore the first assumption is false, so that we can conclude $x=y=z$.